# Camera Not working on windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1

i have lenovo laptop with window 8.1 when i am clicking on camera it's showing that "another app is using camera app first close that app & try again".And any app is not opened.What i do.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to restart your computer and if that does not help you can uninstall the lenovo drivers and just use the windows 8.1 ones because it could be a conflict between the two drivers

Comment: I meant the 8.1 drivers I am used to just calling it windows 8

Answer (score 1):

If it's not a driver issue: You can also try, to deactivate the camera in device manager. After it, reactivate it again. If there really was an app using it, you've stolen it from that app, and it's possible now to get the handle on the camera.

Later you can try to use process manager to find the nasty app.

Answer (score 1):

Process manager is your best bet. Look for anything that might possibly use your camera. Lenovo laptops like that often come with a lot of bloatware that might use the camera. Also try restarting your computer, and disabling the camera in the device manager.

Comment: How would disabling the camera solve the OP's problem, given it's reasonable to assume they're asking this question so that they can actually use the camera?

Comment: If an app is using the camera, then disabling the camera would stop the app from using the camera.